# Making Name block read only in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I want to make the default name block in Magento 2.3 as read only.
This is the block which is used every where. `/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/widget/name.phtml`
If i override this file and make first name and last name read only, it get affected every where.
I want to make the first name, last name fields readonly only at Account Edit information form. https://prnt.sc/oj7taq
But the field becomes read only at Account creation form also. https://prnt.sc/oj7tjj.

How can i make the fields read only at only Edit Account information page.
Please help.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: This is my edit.phtml file https://prnt.sc/oj7yai.......This is my name.phtml file https://prnt.sc/oj7z0w

Answer (score 0):

> You can try following code

```
$currentFullAction = $block->getRequest()->getFullActionName();
if($currentFullAction == "customer_account_editPost"){
    // you can make your changes here
    // In your case, you can add **readonly** attribute in input tag
}
```

> In your phtml file

**Object Manager is not recommended way**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$request = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');
$action = $request->getFullActionName();
if($action == 'customer_account_editPost'){
   // your changes
}
?>
```

**Hope it Helps.**

Comment: Can u tell me in which file?

Comment: in your block file